# How to do MenuItem.addActionListener in PrimeFaces 4.0?

Tags: primefaces

I updated PF 3.5 to 4.0 and this peace of code doesn't compile anymore.

```
MenuItem itemNone = new MenuItem();
itemNone.setValue(Constants.MULTI_SELECT_NONE);
itemNone.setUpdate(UPDATE_AREA_ID);
itemNone.setAjax(true);
itemNone.addActionListener(actionListenerASG);
```

I replaced `MenuItem` with `DefaultMenuItem` and now I only have one problem left:

"The method addActionListener(MethodExpressionActionListener) is undefined for the type DefaultMenuItem",

that's last line of code:

```
itemNone.addActionListener(actionListenerASG);
```

How do I implement this in PrimeFaces 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an action called, you can do the following:

```
itemNone.setCommand("#{myBean.myAction}");
```

Where the action should look like:

```
public void myAction(){
    //whatever this should do
}
```

If you need to know, which MenuItem has been clicked, what I am currently struggling with, here you have a hint for an approach: [Primefaces 4, dynamic menu setCommand method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741731/primefaces-4-dynamic-menu-setcommand-method)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, the method itemNone.setCommand("#{myBean.myAction}"); doesn't work!
I use a workaround

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.myAction}" />
```

On a page to display