# setCommand on a DefaultMenuItem does not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with using the `setCommand()` on a DefaultMenuItem in a `p:megaMenu`.

I want that when I click on an item in buttonTables.jsf the function `afficherTable()` will be excuted and redirect me to affichageTable.jsf. The problem is when I run the project my megaMenu filled, and when I click on an item, it redirect me to the other page, but the fuction `afficherTable()` passed in `setCommand` does not run. So my datatable in the other page is empty. In the console of eclipse I don't have any error. Thank you.

My bean:

```
public class MonBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5773011533863117274L;
    private GestionTableImpl gestionTable;
    private Table table;
    private List<Colonne> columns;
    private  DefaultMenuModel megaModel;

    public void afficherTable(ActionEvent event){
        MenuItem menuItem = ((MenuActionEvent) event).getMenuItem();
        String nTable = menuItem.getParams().get("tableNom").get(0);
        gestionTable=new GestionTableImpl();
        columns=new  ArrayList<Colonne>();
        columns=gestionTable.afficherTable(nTable);
    }

    public  DefaultMenuModel listTablesMenu() {
        gestionTable=new GestionTableImpl();
        List<Table> mesTables=gestionTable.getTables();
        megaModel = new DefaultMenuModel();
        DefaultSubMenu firstSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Tables");

        for(int i=0;i< mesTables.size();i++){
            String tableNom=mesTables.get(i).getNomTable();
            DefaultMenuItem item= new DefaultMenuItem(tableNom);
            item.setUrl("//AffichageTable.jsf");
            item.setIcon("ui-icon-document-b");
            item.setParam("tableNom",item.getValue());
            item.setCommand("#{monBean.afficherTable}");
            firstSubmenu.addElement(item);  
            megaModel.addElement(firstSubmenu);
        }

        return megaModel;
    }

    //getters and setters   
    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
    public void setModel(DynaFormModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public Table getTable() {
        return table;
    }
    public void setTable(Table table) {
        this.table = table;
    }
    public List<Colonne> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }
    public void setColumns(List<Colonne> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }
    public GestionTableImpl getGestionTable() {
        return gestionTable;
    }
    public void setGestionTable(GestionTableImpl gestionTable) {
        this.gestionTable = gestionTable;
    }
    public DefaultMenuModel getMegaModel() {
        return megaModel;
    }
    public void setMegaModel(DefaultMenuModel megaModel) {
        this.megaModel = megaModel;
    }
}
```

This is buttonTables.jsf

```
<body>
    <p:megaMenu autoDisplay="false" styleClass="menu-bar" style="">
        <p:submenu label="Maintenance Services" icon="ui-icon-check">
            <p:column>
            <p:scrollPanel style="height:200px;width:250px" mode="native">
                <p:menu model="#{monBean.listTablesMenu()}" />
                    </p:scrollPanel>            
            </p:column>
        </p:submenu>
    </p:megaMenu>
</body>
```

This is AffichageTable.jsf

```
<h:form>
    <p:outputLabel value="#{monBean.table.nomTable}"/>
        <p:dataTable id="tbl" var="col" value="#{monBean.columns}"
            paginator="true" rows="5" style="margin-bottom:20px">
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Nom colonne" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{col.nomColonne}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Type colonne" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{col.typeColonne}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText />
                </f:facet>
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" />
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: post code inline, not via links and certainly not in images. Please also use capitals when starting a new sentence, and I (i) is with a capital I. And your bean code is not a bean, it is code snipptes. Please read [ask] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and [mcve]

Comment: i tried to update my question , thank you.

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741731/primefaces-4-dynamic-menu-setcommand-method

Comment: thank you, I have already followed this solution, and my code based on it.. but it doesn't work.. I dont know why the function  afficherTable() does not execute when I click on the item !!

Comment: 'Does not work' is not smart, it is not something a developer should say (more a statement by an end-user) Any errors anywhere? Checked network traffic? Added a messages tag? Etc..

Comment: there is no error .. The problem is when I click on the item the redirection works but the function afficheTable() does not excute..I put system.out.println("bla bla bla") in the beginning of my function, but nothing is showed in the console ( I'm sorry, my english is bad ) :/

Answer (score 0):

I had exact the same issue. I made it work by not combining setCommand and setUrl. When I use setUrl, setCommand is not triggered, but everything else gets executed. This is not clear from the primefaces user guide...

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the method in you command to retun the xhtml that you want to redirect something like this:

```
public String afficherTable(){
    MenuItem menuItem = ((MenuActionEvent) event).getMenuItem();
    String nTable = menuItem.getParams().get("tableNom").get(0);
    gestionTable=new GestionTableImpl();
    columns=new  ArrayList<Colonne>();
    columns=gestionTable.afficherTable(nTable);
    return "/AffichageTable.jsf"
}
```